# How to restore the top panel?

Tags: unity, 11.10

I've upgraded my desktop from Natty To Oneiric.
Now the top panel has wrong theme and some indicators are missing (sound, power, etc.). Also, icons in launchers and on the desktop are missing or corrupted:
[image: screenshot]

Logging with other users in same PC is no issue; in that case the top bar is correct.
I've also filed a bug in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/874962).

Is there a way to restore the bar?

Comment: just delete or rename all hidden folders that starts with '.gnome' in your home directory . Then logout and login back. everything will be al right

Comment: @aneeshep: it did not work.

Comment: It seems that it’s a GNOME Settings Daaemon bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the workaround [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11314525&postcount=8):

```
sudo rm /usr/share/GConf/gsettings/pythonconsole.convert
gsettings-data-convert
gnome-settings-daemon
```

Then, to solve definitely at every login, I had to create a launcher to *gnome-settings-daemon* in my home folder and add it to my startup applications.

Answer (score 1):

If unity is a bit broken you could try resetting it - see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) for more details, but the short version is to open a terminal and type:

```
unity --reset
```

Also it might be worth uninstalling the nautilus-open-terminal package if you had it installed - this caused compiz crashes ([launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/865115)) which might lead to your problems. The fix is currently in the oneiric-proposed repository, and should be generally available soon, but not quite yet.

Comment: Resetting Unity does not lead to any improvement. Also, nautilus-open-terminal is not installed in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Three separate issues ..

(1.) Unity Launcher

This button-bar (right-hand of screen) replaces the menu system available as 'Classic' in Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty).  You can try an go back, but I'm not sure I recommend it.

see:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/08/installing-using-classic-gnome-desktop.html

(2.)  missing icons (on button bar)

The default theme is flawed, after upgrade to 11.10 (from 11.04).

Click on top right corner icon; 'Systems Settings' > Appearance > choose 'Radiance'

(3.)  missing icons (on desktop)

This is going to require more effort.

By 'default' Ubuntu 11.10 and Unity (3D) does NOT use the desktop (and icons), but instead used the launcher.  This is a work in progress ..